# How to get notified when NSWindow closes

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit, nswindowcontroller

how can I take notice when an NSWindow should or will get closed? I'd like to have something like the windowWillClose. Unfortunately NSWindowController does not have as much convenient methods as UIViewController has, for example. So what's the best practice to do that?

Thanks
–f

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the `NSWindow` docs, a window will post a `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification when it is about to close. Your controller can observe this notification.

Comment: It will also send its delegate a `windowWillClose:` message: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillClose: So, Cocoa does have something very much like `windowWillClose:`. ☺

Comment: is there such thing as `windowDidClose`?

Comment: There is no such thing as windowDidClose. You have to listen for NSWindowWillCloseNotification or the delegate windowWillClose.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are running with `NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited` in order to hide the dock icon, then none of the delegate methods get called, and the notifications don't get sent.